# Raising Events from another Class - workaround

Tags: c#

I need to Raise an Event from another Class - i know that this is not possible - but I need a workaround for this.

For now Im doing the following

This is the class, which have to raise the event

```
internal class DataTransfer
{
  public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, OnReaderCommonEventArgs e);
  public event EventHandler _OnSerialNumber;
  public event EventHandler _OnReaderType

Task DataHandler()
{
 //Recieving-Data and Stuff
_OnSerialNumber(this, new OnReaderCommonEventArgs { SerialNumber = RFIDParser.ParseSerialNumber(data) });
_OnReaderType(this, new OnReaderCommonEventArgs { ReaderType = RFIDParser.ParseReaderType(data) });
}
}
```

And in the Main-Class, which will be used by the user. So the user can only subscribe to the event from this class-object:

```
public partial class PUR_100U
{
        public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, OnReaderCommonEventArgs e);
        public event EventHandler OnSerialNumber;
        public event EventHandler OnReaderType;

        public PUR_100U(int portnumber)
        {
            dataTransfer = new DataTransfer(portnumber, GetIdentifierList());

            dataTransfer._OnSerialNumber += dataTransfer__OnSerialNumber;
            dataTransfer._OnReaderType += dataTransfer__OnReaderType;
        }
        void dataTransfer__OnSerialNumber(object sender, OnReaderCommonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (OnSerialNumber != null) { OnSerialNumber(this, new OnReaderCommonEventArgs { SerialNumber = e.SerialNumber }); }
        }

        void dataTransfer__OnReaderType(object sender, OnReaderCommonEventArgs e)
        {
           if (OnReaderType != null) { OnReaderType(this, new OnReaderCommonEventArgs { ReaderType = e.ReaderType }); }
        }
}
```

Example of user-usage:

```
rfid = new PUR_100U(20);
rfid.OnSerialNumber += rfid_OnSerialNumber;
rfid.OnReaderType += rfid_OnReaderType;
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: So what is your problem with this code? Does it work?

Comment: It is working, but it seems a bit weired to subscribe to an event from a "helper-class" and then raise the exact same event in the main class, just to delegate it to the user. So my Question is: Is there a cleaner way of doing such thing (raise an event in another class and let the user subscribe to it from the main class)

Comment: Use `add` and `remove`. But you will still need to introduce an `event` in your main class.

Comment: Your second class (PUR_100U) can simply derive from the first class (DataTransfer), without defining events again.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't look very healthy.  The `data` falls from the sky, surely that needs to come from somewhere and there ought to be a method that accepts it as an argument.  That method can then trivially also fire the events.   Also best if the event source is a more permanent object, more permanent than a "data transfer".  If whatever class that generates the `data` needs to be hidden then maybe this needs a public "DataManager" class to wrap it.

Comment: the `On` prefix is usually used for the method that invokes the event, not the event itself. A more common name IMO would be for instance SerialNumberChanged. See the [microsoft naming convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to Raise an Event from another Class - i know that this is not possible - but I need a workaround for this.

That is rather trivial:

```
class Foo
{
    public event EventHandler Fooed; //note, name is not OnFoo
    public void FireFooed() => Fooed?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs);
}
```

And now, fire the event at will:

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.FireFooed();
```

The question is, why do you want to do this? It seems like a really bad idea. `Fooed` should fire *only and only if* the preconditions inside `Foo` for it to fire are met; if you need `Fooed` to fire, then *make the preconditions happen*!

Firing `Fooed` at will if the conditions aren't met will break all other listeners, *don't do that*.